# How does g++ compiler know which vtable ptr to use if their are multiple vtable ptr in a base class?

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-construction, g++, vtable

I want to know know how does g++ compiler knows which table to use if their are multiple vtable present in a base class. Like the following example.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

class sample1
{
private:
    int b;
public:
    sample1():b(34)
    {
        cout << "In sample1 constructor" << endl;
    }
    virtual void print_b()
    {
        cout << this->b << endl;
    }
    void print_all()
    {
        this->print_b();
    }
    void sample_print_()
    {
        //cout << this->a << "String : " << this->str1 << endl;
        cout << "hello" << endl;
        this->print_all();  
    }
 };

class sample2
{
private:
    int b1;
public:
    sample2():b1(34)
    {
        cout << "In sample1 constructor" << endl;
    }
    virtual void print_b1()
    {
        cout << this->b1 << endl;
    }
    void print_all1()
    {
        this->print_b1();
    }
};

class sample : public sample1 , public sample2
{
private:
    int a;
    char *str1;

public:
sample():a(12),sample1()
{
    strcpy(this->str1,"hello world");
    cout << "In Constructor" << endl;
}
~sample()
{
    free(this->str1);
    cout << "In Destructor" << endl;
}
void sample_print()
{
    //cout << this->a << "String : " << this->str1 << endl;
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    this->print_all();
}
    virtual void print_a()
    {
      cout << this->a <<endl;
    }
};
```

In above example, child class sample has two parent classes sample1 and sample2 and each of these class have vtable of their own. What if i call a virtual function from sample(child class)? How does the compiler know, in which class that virtual function is present so that it call use that particular vtable pointer ? I know their will be two vtable pointer present in sample(child class) class , so how does compiler know which one to use ?

Comment: `i call a virtual function from sample...  in which class that virtual function is present?` In `sample`, of course. What exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: This is completely implementation dependent & how every compiler implements this can be completely different. Only guarantee you have is you can rely on the compiler(*ofcourse a commercial grade one*) to the *right thing*

Comment: @AlokSave: Well, the question is, and I quote, "How does g++ compiler know..."

Comment: I recommend the book: `Inside the C++ Object Model` to you, if you have more time to learn it.

Comment: I want to know how does the compiler know which vptr to use to find the appropriate virtual function as their will be two vptr present in any instance of class sample.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I completely missed that because there is no mention in the Q body, that Q title surely will get modified & reference to the particular compiler will get lost. Also, OP seems to be oblivious to the fact that it is implementation dependendent or atleast it appears so from the comments.

Comment: There are in fact *three* vtable pointers present in any instance of `sample` class - one for `sample` itself, and one for each of its bases (well, there may be two; it is often possible for the compiler to combine the vtable of derived class with one of its bases, when one is a prefix of another). If you call through `sample*` pointer or reference, you would use `sample`'s vtable pointer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik actually their are only vtable ptr as compiler combined two of them at offset 0 of class. and sample* pointer doesn't have virtual functions from other of its parent class so it would be wrong to say that it will use only sample* vtable ptr.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. There's a vtable pointer at offset zero in `sample` - call it whatever you want, but that's the one the compiler would be using when you call a virtual function through `sample*` pointer. The compiler can't rely on `sample` overriding or not overriding any virtual functions - for all it knows, that `sample` pointer actually points to some class derived from `sample` that overrides everything.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i think what u are saying is correct but the vtable at offset 0 is incomplete,it doesn't have print_b1 , print_all1 from class sample2,which must be their in vtable, these functions are present in another vtable ptr at certain offset(not 0). What happens if i call one of these function ? Would the compiler will still use the vtable ptr at offset 0 ?

Comment: `vtable at offset 0 is incomplete,it doesn't have...` What makes you believe so? I'm pretty sure it is and it does. Yes, pointers to these functions are *also* present in another vtable.

Comment: vtable at offset 0 - http://s27.postimg.org/5kdk5v9ur/1_cropped.jpg | vtable at offset 0x10 - http://s27.postimg.org/4mk60affn/2_cropped.jpg

Comment: @IgorTandetnik vtable at offset 0 has - print_a , print_b | vtable at offset 0x10 has print_b1 . that mean i can't call print_b1 function from offset 0 vptr of class but i must be able to, according to u . I think it clears my point.

Comment: How do you determine that? I'm pretty sure vtable at offset 0 contains three pointers: to `print_b`, `print_b1` and `print_a`, in that order.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik No it doesn't. I also added the pics, you can check them out. I am correct.

Comment: Ok, well, then, there's a second vtable, also at a fixed, well-known offset (though not 0) from the beginning of `sample`, containing pointers to a fixed, well-known subset of virtual functions. The bottom line is, there's no difficulty for the compiler to retrieve the right pointer from the right vtable. The class layout is known at compile time - the compiler laid it out itself, after all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62944/discussion-between-in3o-and-igor-tandetnik).